# Remove underline for a div inside a Link

Tags: html, css

I have this structure:

```
<a href="" class="link">
 <div>
   <div class="innerdiv-with-underline">text with underline</div>
   <div class="innerdiv-without-underline">text</div>
 </div>
</a>
```

I would like that on **:hover** only the text inside innerdiv-without-underline **would not be** underlined.

I have tried this with no luck:

```
.link .innerdiv {
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

What can I do ?

Comment: make the element inline-block and add `width:100%` to keep it's behavior as block element if you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use `text-decoration` property in the class `.link` instead of class `.innerdiv`

```css
.link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link:hover .innerdiv-with-underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="link">
 <div>
   <div class="innerdiv-with-underline">text with underline</div>
   <div class="innerdiv-without-underline">text</div>
 </div>
</a>
```

Comment: thanks +1, i reformulated the question, because i need one div with underline and the second without

Comment: ok thanks, i am trying to understand why your code deosn't work for me inside a boostrap4 page

Comment: ok got it, in your first css i add to do this: .link, .link:hover {...}

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `innerdiv` from `.link .innerdiv`CSS, as `achor` tag has text-decoration css property assigned, not DIV

```
.link  {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: thanks +1, i reformulated the question, because i need one div with underline and the second without

Answer (score 0):

Your css rule is this:

```
.link .innerdiv {
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

First of all there is no class named `innerdiv`. You might've meant `innerdiv-without-underline`. So probably you should have used this:

```
.link .innerdiv-with-underline {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Alas, this wouldn't work either. Since the underline is coming from the decoration of the `<a>` tag not `<div>` tag. So specifying a rule for only the div won't work. What you could have done is:

```
.link {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

This will remove underlines from all the links. But now you want one to have underline on hover and another to not.

```
.link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link:hover .innerdiv-with-underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```